# What composite number can be represented as $\binom{n}{k}$ for $k\neq1$ or $n-1$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-number-theory

This is a problem I came up with when I was working with binomial coefficients. Let's call the title statement $(*)$. Obviously for any primes do not satisfy $(*)$, therefore we only need to focus on composite numbers.

How can I proceed?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A006987

Comment: Thank you for the link! But I hope that one can analyse these numbers instead of listing them.